# select subquery in insert query for PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to use a SELECT subquery into a INSERT query as PreparedStatement...
I am trying to fill 2 columns with custom value and the 3rd one with subquery...

```
query = "insert into invoiceOrders (productCode,quantity,amount) values (?,?,select price from priceTable where proCode=pCode)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(0,"productCode");
stmt.setString(1,"qty");
/*3rd column will be filled be subquery*/
n = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You have to describe your actual problem and ask a question. Right now it looks like you stopped halfway with writing your question. One tip, JDBC parameter indexes are 1-based, so `setString(0, ...)` is wrong, that should be `setString(1, ...)`

Comment: Your select can only reference itself, so it is unclear how much sense "proCode=pCode" makes. Do you need a parameter for the subquery? Also, unless MySQL can be sure in all cases that such a select will return only one value, it will reject it as a source for an insert field; you'll need a `LIMIT 1` on the select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery:

```
select price from priceTable where proCode=pCode
```

must be enclosed in parentheses and make sure that **it returns only 1 row**.
Also what is the parameter `pCode`? 
I think that you should replace it with `?` and pass later its value with `setString()`. 
Also the `setString()` method's 1st argument is 1 based.  
So change to this:

```
query = "insert into invoiceOrders (productCode,quantity,amount) values (?,?,(select price from priceTable where proCode=?))";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1,"productCode");
stmt.setString(2,"qty");
stmt.setString(3,pCode);  // or stmt.setInt(3,pCode);
n = stmt.executeUpdate();
```